# Objective-C Convention for Accessing a Computed (Readonly) Property in an Initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax

In the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW11), it is recommended that accessors are not used to get/set ivars in an initializer. It is an understandable recommendation given that accessors can be overridden and side-affects introduced. So, I wanted to get opinions whether or not it is conventional to access computed properties (i.e. properties without ivars) using dot-notation in an initializer. Here's an example:

```
// private computed property without ivar synthesized
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *anArray;

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super initWithSomeArray:self.anArray])) {
        // extra initialization work
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)anArray {
    return @[@(0), @(1)]; // some array
}
```

So, what is the convention for accessing computed properties in initializer? If just the docs are the authority, it would seem perfectly acceptable. However, I can see how this could create some confusion given that dot notation in initializers is downplayed given the reasons above. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know that there's a recognized convention for this, but you can always use bracket notation vs dot notation as a hint (e.g. `[self anArray]`). A question I have though is upon what basis is the property synthesized? If it relies on other instance state then you're still using the object before initialization is complete.  And if it doesn't rely on instance state, why not make it a class method instead and avoid the confusion?

Comment: @BenZotto, not sure if this answers your question, but here's a snippet from Apple's docs that talk about the criteria for automatic ivar synthesis: [http://i.imgur.com/VcJdcp9.png](http://i.imgur.com/VcJdcp9.png).

Comment: I'm asking about your object specifically. If you were really just returning a static array, that probably shouldn't be an instance property to begin with (or certainly doesn't have to be). I assume you're actually doing more than that, but does what you're doing require in turn accessing other `self` state?

Comment: Apologies, I should have read your question more closely. Yes, in my case, the property does not rely on any instance state and is purely distinct. I could see it being a private class method. I suppose the only justification I have for making it a property is that I believe it to be (conceptually) more intuitive.

Comment: Ok then there's one answer. :) You can create a class method that does this work for you, and call that from the initializer. If you like the existing abstraction, you can keep your existing "instance" version which can be just a wrapper around the private class method version. (The design discussion around when methods should be `+` versus `-` can be subtle and subjective. One school of thought holds that any method which doesn't touch object state should be a class method. I tend to think that sometimes an external caller's expectations can mitigate that.)